# Can't find gitlab-ci-multi-runner package

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to install `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` on ElementaryOS **Freya**, but having no success.

I've correctly follow the steps in official documentation:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-repository.md#install-using-official-gitlab-repositories

The answer always is:

```
luiz@kryptonita:~/node/my-nodejs-app$ sudo apt-get install gitlab-ci-multi-runner
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gitlab-ci-multi-runner
```

To understand: I'm trying to set up a Runner to test a Node.js "Hello World". I'm studying this technology.

**EDIT:** Result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runner_gitlab-ci-multi-runner.list`

```
# this file was generated by packages.gitlab.com for
# the repository at https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner

deb https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/elementaryos/ freya main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/elementaryos/ freya main
```

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runner_gitlab-ci-multi-runner.list`?

Comment: I've edited the post with the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed they do not have repos for elementary os freya. I see two possible solutions:

### Method 1: Using Ubuntu Repos

Now, I'm not sure this procedure works, but since freya is bases on Ubuntu 14.04, I think you can use trusty's repo.

**Careful** this can potentially breaks things and dependencies, I **have not** tested it.

Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/runner_gitlab-ci-multi-runner.list` file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runner_gitlab-ci-multi-runner.list
```

Delete all and add

```
deb https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

Then do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gitlab-ci-multi-runner`

In this way you have automatic updates.

### Method 2: Manually download the package

If you prefer to do not add a PPA studied for another distro, just download the package from the website ([here a list of the packages](https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner?filter=debs)). but in this way you have to manually update the program each time!

Otherwise you can use docker/lxc/virtualbox to install Ubuntu (or Fedora or whatever is official supported) and use it

Comment: Link in method 2 downloads an outdated package

Comment: @qznc right, unfortunately they do not have an alias for the last version. I updated the answer inserting a link to the list of packages

Answer (score 1):

Only this worked for me:

```
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

From: https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/install